# Grails remoteFunction AJAX function in a GSP, accessing variable to use for params

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.0

I am wanting to **dynamically set the params** in a **remoteFunction** within a check box. I have tried lots of different combinations I'll show a couple below but I just recieve error like below...

so it basically my theory, in the scope of this method doesn't have a clue what an eventInstance is

In *FireBug error console* I receive `ReferenceError: eventInstance is not defined`

```
Test Combination 1
<g:checkBox name='completed' value="${eventInstance.completed}"
    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'update', id:eventInstance.id, params:'\'id=\' + eventInstance.id+\'&version=\' + eventInstance.version' , onComplete: "tester()" )}" />


Test Combination 2 
<g:checkBox name='completed' value="${eventInstance.completed}" evt="${eventInstance}"
    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'update', id:eventInstance.id, params:"[version=evt.version, editType='occurrence', title=evt.title, startTime=start, endTime=end, isRecurring=evt.isRecurring, completed='true']", onComplete: "tester()" )}" />
```

This works if manually entering i.e. hard-coding the data in but this is no use. Something silly which I just can't find the answer to :(

Comment: Where was the error message `ReferenceError: eventInstance is not defined`  shown, firebug or the web page?

Comment: FireBug, sorry if I wasn't clear. It was indeed in the console with FireFox.

Comment: Well, it is clear in your question. I just want to double check it. So what did the gsp view render? Is there a checkbox in the page?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question this would work if manually entered in such as id and any other of the param data... but I want to set this dynamically using a variable useable in the GSP from the controller. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK for this to work ... seems somewhat strange, you **CAN NOT** use grails variables i.e. sent from controller to use in GSP

Instead ... you **HAVE TO** save the variables into a JavaScript variable.

So for each of the variables I wanted to use from the `eventInstance` to use in the `params` i.e. id, version, any other fields contained within I simply did the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tester() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }

    var test0 = ${eventInstance.id};
    var test1 = ${eventInstance.version};
    var test3 ='${eventInstance.title}';
    var test4 = '${start}';
    var test5 = '${end}';
    var test6 = ${eventInstance.isRecurring};
    alert(test0 + test1 + test3 + test4 + test5 + test5 + 
</script>
```

then referenced these variables in the params section of the `remoteFunction` like follows:

```
<g:checkBox name='completed' value="${eventInstance.completed}"
onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'update', id:eventInstance.id, params:'\'id=\' + test0+\'&version=\' + test1+\'&editType=\'+"occurrence"', onComplete: "tester()" )}" />
```

Not sure if this is some kind of bug or simply something wrong in my approach, however I have tried every single combination possible and seems the only work around solution I could come up with

Comment: Does seem a somewhat waste in memory having to copy variable instances, I would of hoped there would of been a work around... doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 1):

this can help you,

```
onchange="${remoteFunction(asynchronous: false, controller: 'mycontroller', action: 'remoteMethod', params: '\'p1='+params?.p1+'&p2=less&p3=\'+ this.value', update: 'remoteDiv')}"
```

just try this one.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you,

```
    onchange="$
    {
         remoteFunction(asynchronous: false, 
              controller: 'mycontroller', 
              action: 'remoteMethod', 
              params: '\'p1='+params?.p1+'&p2=less&p3=\'+ this.value', update: 'remoteDiv')}"
```

just try this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I don't think you've read the question ... that doesn't help. Also not sure if you've tested that, however it appears that it is not possible to use the Grails params sent from a controller in the way I need to use them in the params sent back to the controller. Look at the question closely, the way I've done below in my own answer appears to work... however _hacky_ it may appear

Comment: are you passing all value from controller as model?